# Issue while passing variable value from server side code to javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I have simple rails application to upload mp3 files to Amazon S3 and then play back it on site.

Issue I am facing is while passing mp3 url from ruby to javascript function.

```
<% audio = @random_audio %>
//<%= raise audio.song.url.inspect %>  
//console.log('<%= audio.song.url %>');
wavesurfer.load('<%= audio.song.url %>');
```

raise gives correct url

```
 uploads/test.mp3?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXX&Signature=XXX&Expires=1392962027
```

but console log gives wrong url, it adds `amp;` after each `&`

```
 uploads/test.mp3?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXX&amp;Signature=XXX&amp;Expires=1392962027
```

Because of this audio file can't be accessed. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= audio.song.url.html_safe %>
```